# Disabling PDF Viewer plugin in chromedriver

Tags: python, python-2.7, selenium, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to batch-download a lot of files within the BlackBoard environment (used a lot on universities/schools around the world). I am able to retrieve the links where the files are but one mayor issue:

When the file is a .pdf-file, it is shown in a new browser-tab in stead of being downloaded. For e.g. .xlsx-files downloading with a click() works just fine..

Can I change the driversettings to change this behaviour? And how?

**Edit**
 I updated the question in reaction to Ari's answer. It's now including more info on the actual plugin. Maybe that's usable to identify the plugin which has to be disabled..

```
Chrome PDF Viewer (2 files)

   Name:            Chrome PDF Viewer
       Version: 
       Location:    chrome-extension://mhjfbmdgcfjbbpaeojofohoefgiehjai/
       Type:        BROWSER PLUGIN
                    Disable
       MIME types:  MIME type        Description     File extensions
                    application/pdf                  .pdf

   Name:            Chrome PDF Viewer
       Description: Portable Document Format
       Version: 
       Location:    internal-pdf-viewer
       Type:        PPAPI (out-of-process)
                    Disable
       MIME types:  MIME type        Description    File extensions
                    application/x-google-chrome-pdf Portable Document Format    
                    .pdf
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ari's answer was almost working properly. I only needed to encapsulate the plugin's name into a list:

```
chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"plugins.plugins_disabled" : ["Chrome PDF Viewer"]} # Here should be a list
chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
chromedriver = "path/to/chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver, chrome_options=chromeOptions)
```

The downloading now works just fine!

Comment: Weird, glad you got it working, and you've taught me something about chromedriver! :)

Comment: This seems not to work anymore. See https://gist.github.com/MartinThoma/8b55b296375f83cbe4b70179930e70bd as an example.

Comment: and https://www.ghacks.net/2017/01/29/google-removes-plugin-controls-from-chrome/

Comment: Most recently solved with this command: 
`prefs = {"plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True}`

Answer (score 10):

Chrome 57 change the setting...
use this to disable Chrome PDF viewer:

```
//To disable PDF viewer plugins with Chrome 57
chromePrefs.put("plugins.always_open_pdf_externally", true);
```

Comment: Indeed, `'plugins.plugins_disabled': ["Chrome PDF Viewer"],` doesn't work anymore (since Chrome 57)! Thank you, you have the right solution! How did you find that?

Comment: In Python, use: `chrome_options = webdriver.ChromeOptions(); chrome_options.add_experimental_option("prefs", {"download.prompt_for_download": False, "plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True})`

Comment: In Robotframework, use:
`${prefs}    Create Dictionary    download.default_directory    ${CURDIR}    plugins.always_open_pdf_externally    ${TRUE}` 

Note the usage of `Create Dictionary` and `${TRUE}`

Answer (score 1):

Can you set the plugin to be disable as a preference?

```
chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
prefs = {"plugins.plugins_disabled" : "Chrome PDF Viewer"}
chromeOptions.add_experimental_option("prefs",prefs)
chromedriver = "path/to/chromedriver.exe"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=chromedriver, chrome_options=chromeOptions)
```

See "[setting Chrome preferences w/ Selenium Webdriver in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18026391/setting-chrome-preferences-w-selenium-webdriver-in-python?rq=1)" and "[How to disable Chrome Plugins in Selenium WebDriver using Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37617061/how-to-disable-chrome-plugins-in-selenium-webdriver-using-java)".

Comment: Thanks, but not working for me.. It doesn't disable the plugin when I check it. I updated the question, it's now including more info on the actual plugin. Maybe thats usable to identify the plugin which has to be disabled..

Answer (score 0):

```
options = Options()
source_dir = r"C:\Users\........"

profile = {"download.prompt_for_download": False, "plugins.always_open_pdf_externally": True,
           "download.default_directory": source_dir}
options.add_experimental_option("prefs", profile)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(service=ChromeService(ChromeDriverManager().install()), chrome_options=options)
```

Comment: Please provide additional information for your code.